# Can there be Parallel for Async in cats effect?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I noticed that cats-effect typeclass hierarchy doesn't inherit `Parallel` from cats core even at their most powerful typeclass `ConcurrentEffect`. The only instance provided for parallel exists only if you use IO directly.

But shouldn't there be one? I kinda feel like `Sync[F]` and `Async[F]` should be a nice duo for `Parallel[F]`.

Answer (score 5):

The `Parallel` behavior is really different to what `Sync` and `Async` hierarchy promises (that is sequential but (a)synchronous execution). `ConcurrentEffect` promises that your computation runs on a thread pool and can be cancelled (+ everything its smaller elements promise) - still not enable combining parallel computations but allows you to implement races. `Parallel` is an orthogonal semantics which is why it is passed as a separate type class/type constraint. So just add it as a separate type constraint.

```
def toStringParallel[F[_]: Sync: Parallel](list: List[F[Int]]): F[List[String]] =
  list.parTraverse(a => a.toString.pure[F])

object App1 extends IOApp {
  def run(args: List[String]) = toStringParallel[IO](List(IO(1), IO(2)))
    .as(ExitCode.Success)
}
```

If you cannot instantiate `Parallel[IO]`, remember that [it requires `ContextShift[IO]` to create an instant of Parallel[IO]](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect/blob/0cdd977237792cf41b2c093684e591160cfee394/site/src/main/mdoc/datatypes/io.md#parallelism).

```
// example from docs
implicit val contextShift: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)

val ioA = IO(println("Running ioA"))
val ioB = IO(println("Running ioB"))
val ioC = IO(println("Running ioC"))

// make sure that you have an implicit ContextShift[IO] in scope. 
val program = (ioA, ioB, ioC).parMapN { (_, _, _) => () }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get what you're saying. But I'm still wondering if you can derive an instance of parallel for Async given ContextShift? For parallel F ~> F we can do Async.shift *> f, for sequential F ~> F we can do Sync.delay. Or something in line with that

Answer (score 1):

As of cats-effect 3, `Parallel` is available implicitly for anything inheriting `Spawn[F]`, which includes `Concurrent[F]` and `Async[F]`

It requires an import:

```
import cats.effect.implicits._
```

It needs an import because `Parallel` is in cats while `Spawn` and the rest are in cats-effect. There's no scope where the implicit can be in the cats-effect library such that the compiler is aware to check (for example) `Concurrent` when trying to discover a `Parallel`